# Converter API for doc, docx, rtf, txt, xls, xslx, pdf to HTML/HTM format for web application without using MS Office in back end

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need a third party API to convert **doc, docx, rtf, txt, xls, xslx, pdf into HTML/HTM ** format without using MS Office component(MSWORD/EXCEL) in backend. This API must support RELATIVE path for images as I will use it in ASP.NET Web based application.

Please help me out, money is not a concern, Paid API's are also preferable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might not be the answer you're looking for, but there is a JAVA library that can read doc, docx, xls and xlsx formats (ApachePOI), so you could analyze the file and create the HTML output yourself. It does support relative paths afaik.
Of course it would require a lot of custom coding, also you would have to include the Java library in C# (though I remember having heard that this isn't so hard, never tried it though).

Hope this helps

Comment: "create the HTML output yourself" - that's very much not trivial. There is a .NET port of POI called [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com).